# Compare date and datetime

Tags: php, sql, datetime, compare

I want to compare a datetime from sql and the todays date.
The datetime in sql is for example 2015/05/09 12:00:00 and the current date is  2015/05/09. I want to compare these things if they are equal, but for the whole day so the time is a problem. I have the following query.

```
$q1="SELECT reservations.reservation_id, reservations.room_id,   room.room_rate, reservations.arrival_date, reservations.departure_date,
                            meals.meal_rate, room.room_rate, roomtype.max_persons,
                            CONCAT(clients.first_name,' ',clients.last_name)as name

                    FROM reservations, clients, meals, room, roomtype
                    WHERE reservations.room_id=room.room_id AND reservations.client_id=clients.client_id AND room.roomtype_id=roomtype.roomtype_id 
                    AND reservations.meals=meals.meal_id AND reservations.arrival_date=CURDATE()
                    GROUP BY reservation_id
                    ";
```

reservations.arrival_date=CURDATE() this is equal only at 12:00:00 o'clock. i want that to be equal for the whole day.Actually i want to compare if these two dates are equal without time but my database must be datetime with the time...
does anyone has an idea?
thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn to use standard `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `from` clause.

The answer to your question is either the `date()` function (or something similar):

```
where date(reservations.arrival_date) = CURDATE()
```

Or an inequality:

```
where (reservations.arrival_date >= CURDATE() and
       reservations.arrival_date < date_add(CURDATE(), interval 1 day)
      )
```

The second is actually preferred because it can make use of an index on `reservations(arrival_date)`.

Comment: actually this is an old php code that i wanted to add something.now I am using the join.thnx anyway.
your second solution also works but i just thought sth simpler $today = date("Y-m-d 12:00:00");  and then compare arrivaldate with today!

Comment: @stavros . . . If you always know that the time component is exactly noon, then that would work.